# TypeError: this.props.header is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use the `@ercpereda/react-native-accordion` package's `Accordion` component in my project. Here's the example usage they give in the README:

```
const Header = ({ isOpen }) =>
<View style={{
  paddingTop: 15,
  paddingRight: 15,
  paddingLeft: 15,
  paddingBottom: 15,
  borderBottomWidth: 1,
  borderBottomColor: '#a9a9a9',
  backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
}}>
  <Text>{`${isOpen ? '-' : '+'} Click to Expand`}</Text>
</View>;

...
//inside render method

    <Accordion
      header={Header}
      content={Content}
      duration={300}
    />
```

and here's how I'm trying to render the `Accordion`:

```
            <View>
                {
                    headers.map((item, i) => (
                        <Accordion
                            header={ this.generateHeader(item) }
                            content = { <Text>Hello</Text> }
                        />
                    ))
                }
            </View>
```

with `headers` being defined like so in my render method:

```
    const headers = [
        "Hotel",
        "Arriving Flight",
        "Departing Flight",
        "Restaurants",
        "Bars",
        "Things to Do"
    ];
```

and the method `generateHeader` like so:

```
generateHeader(item) {
    return (
        <Text>{ item }</Text>
    )
}
```

Despite the fact that `generateHeader` is indeed a function, however, I keep getting this error message: `TypeError: this.props.header is not a function (In 'this.props.header({ isOpen: this.state.is_visible })', 'this.props.header' is an instance of Object)`. Why is `generateHeader` not recognized as a function?

Comment: Where are you declaring your prop types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. `this.generateHeader` **is** a function. Is `this.generateHeader(item)` a function though? No it is not.

`this.generateHeader(item)` returns `<Text>{ item }</Text>` which is not a function. Compare that to the example where `Header` **is** a function so that `header={Header}` says "the prop `header` equals the function `Header`".

If `this.generateHeader(item)` returned `() => <Text>{ item }</Text>`, well then it would indeed be a function.

You could also look at it like this:

```
header={() => <Text />}
```

or like this:

```
const Header = () => <Text />
...
header={Header}
...
```

or like this:

```
const generateHeader = item => () => <Text>{item}</Text>
...
header={generateHeader(item)}
...
```